# How to see new results in console after updating imported module in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

When I import a selfmade module and run the program, the output is what I expected. However when I update the module and run the program in the same console, the previous result is shown. If I open a new console, then the new result is correctly shown.

Let's take an example:

```py
# Filename: myfunctions.py

def helloWorld():
    print("Hello World")
```

```py
# Filename: runfuction.py

from myfunctions import helloWorld

helloWorld()
```

The output is `Hello World`. When I replace in myfunctions.py `Hello` into `Bye`, and when I run the program in the same console, my result is still `Hello World`, and not `Bye World`. The updated text `Bye World` will be only shown when I open a new console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
reload(module_name)
```

that's how it works in a local python console.  I don't have a PythonAnywhere account, but I would guess it's pretty similar.

Note that any object instances you have already created will not be changed, but this (or something similar) should work fine for functions.

Comment: A quick note and an upvote from a PythonAnywhere dev here -- yup, that will do the job.

Comment: Thanks!  This question actually inspired me to _get_ a PythonAnywhere account, so I have one now.